# Choosing between Trait and Object

Tags: scala

I was trying to look into `trait` and `object` in scala when it seems like we can use trait and object to do a similar task.

What should be the guiding principles on when to use `trait` and when to use `object`?

Edit:
As many of you are asking for an example

```
object PercentileStats {
 def addPercentile(df: DataFrame): DataFrame // implementation
}

trait PercentileStats {
 def addPercentile(df: DataFrame): DataFrame // implementation
}
```

There is a Process class which can use the object

```
object Process {
 def doSomething(df: DataFrame): DataFrame {
   PercentileStats.addPercentile(df)
 }
}
```

We can also make it use the trait

```
object Process with PercentileStats {
 def doSomething(df: DataFrame): DataFrame {
  addPercentile(df)
 }
}
```

Comment: When can you use trait or object to do a similar task?

Comment: As far as I know, the similarities between `object` and `trait` are no more than similarities between an actual `Starship USS Enterprise` and a half complete drawing of the design for the said `Starship`.

Comment: `I was trying to look into trait and object in scala when it seems like we can use trait and object to do a similar task.`

can you please give some example for the above statement

Comment: An `object` can't be abstract. You can't `extend` (inherit from) an `object`. They aren't very similar at all.

Comment: @jwvh As they are not similar but as I have given an example which should be the preferred way.

Comment: From your example, putting the method `addPercentile()` in an `object` doesn't appear to serve any purpose. The method could stand alone, outside of an enclosing `object`, and be just as effective (and less verbose).

Answer (score 4):

I think the real question here is **Where do I put stand-alone functions?**

There are three options.

#### In the package

You can put stand-alone functions in the outer `package` scope. This makes them immediately available to the whole `package` but the name has to be meaningful across the whole package.

```
def addPercentile(df: DataFrame): DataFrame // implementation
```

#### In an object

You can group stand-alone functions in an `object` to provide a simple namespace. This means that you have to use the name of the object to access the functions, but it keeps them out of the global namespace and allows the names to be simpler:

```
object PercentileStats {
  def add(df: DataFrame): DataFrame // implementation
}
```

#### In a trait

You can group stand-alone functions in a `trait`. This also removes them from the `package` namespace, but allows them to be accessed without a qualifier from classes that have that `trait`. But this also makes the method visible outside the class, and allows them to be overridden. To avoid this you should mark them `protected final`:

```
trait PercentileStats {
  protected final def addPercentile(df: DataFrame): DataFrame // implementation
}
```

#### Which is best?

The choice really depends on how the function will be used. If a function is only to be used in a particular scope then it might make sense to put it in a `trait`, otherwise the other options are better. If there are a number of related function then grouping them in an `object` makes sense. One-off functions for general use can just go in the `package`.

Comment: How can the most extensive and precise answer which actually answers the 'when to use` question be downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Object - is a class that has exactly one instance. It is created lazily when it is referenced, like a lazy val.

As a top-level value, an object is a singleton.

Traits - are used to share interfaces and fields between classes.

Classes and objects can extend while traits cannot be instantiated and therefore have no parameters.

So, it means that if you prefer singleton type implementation with no `new instance` happen then use Object but if you want to `inherit` implementation to other class or objects then you can use trait.

Answer (score 1):

Traits: are equivalent to interfaces in Java. So you can use it to define public contracts like interfaces in Java. In addition, a trait can be used to share values (beside methods) between classes extends the trait.

Objects in Scala is actually quite flexible. Example use cases include:

- singletons: If you think that your objects are singletons (exactly
  one instance exists in the program), you can use object.
- factory: for instance, companion object of a class can be used as factory for creating instances of the class.
- to share static methods: for example, common utilities can be declared in one object.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to consider how you would want to use / import it.

```
trait Foo {
   def test(): String
}

object Bar extends Foo


import Bar._
```

Objects enable you to import rather than mix in your class.

It is a life saver when you want to mock - with scalamock - a class that mixes a lot of traits and expose more than 22 methods that you don't really need exposed in the scope.